# How can I print out only the name and file size using the find command?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find, printf

So I have this command line that works.

```
find . -type f |xargs ls -lS |head -20
```

The thing is I only want the output to be the file size and the name. I tried:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s %p\n' |xargs ls -lS |head -20
```

but this gives me a bunch of 'cannot access [inode], no such file or directory' errors.

My goal is to print the biggest 20 files in the directory, not using ls.

Comment: Just do `find . -type f -printf '%s %p\n'` and drop the `xargs`.

Comment: That does work, but I'm looking to output the biggest 20 files, so I need those xargs and the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find . -type f |xargs ls -lS |head -20 | awk '{print $9, $5}'`

Since the output of `ls` is columnar, just print the proper columns and you're done.

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of `awk` - next stop is averaging values with `cat some.csv | awk '{s+=$4} END {print s/NR}'`

Comment: What happens if a file name contains a space?

Comment: @e0k the code in this answer is completely broken… (spaces or quotes would break it badly). It seems we're having new waves of very bad answers…

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the limitations here! Indeed a 80%/20% type of answer, not to be used without understanding the limitations of `awk`

Comment: This only works when the output of find is small enough for xargs to place into a single call to ls.  Otherwise, it'll split the results into multiple runs of ls and each of those clumps will be sorted, but you'll only see the 20 largest of the _first_ ls called by xargs.

Answer (score 4):

An answer without `ls` involved:

```
find . -type f -printf '%k %p\n' |sort -n |tail -n 20
```

This gives each file, listed with the size (in kB), a space, then the file name, sorted numerically, and then you get the last 20 items (the 20 largest).

Your problem was in piping to `ls`.

If you've got a *really* big directory structure, `sort` will fall over. If you already know the ballpark size and that most files are much smaller, you can tell `find` to rule out smaller sizes with an additional option, e.g. `find . -type f -size +2M -printf …` which prunes out anything under 2MiB. Otherwise, you'd have to use some custom code that stores only the largest 20 items.

Answer (score 2):

Use following commmand to get size of the fiule in linux.

```
du -h <<FileName>>
```

Or

```
du -h <<FilePath>>
```

Comment: Good start, but this doesn't use the `find` command and doesn't sort. Since you've given human-readable units, you'll need to sort with that in mind. GNU `sort -h` will work.

Answer (score 2):

In the question, you state:

> My goal is to print the biggest 20 files in the directory, not using ls.

This implies that an acceptable solution *should not use* `ls`.

Another issue is the use of `xargs`.  A construction like `find . -type f | xargs ls` will not work with subdirectory or file names containing white space, since it will split the string from `find` before giving it to `ls`.  You can protect the string or work around this using null terminated strings, such as `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls`.  In general, there are [security considerations](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Security-Considerations-for-xargs.html) for using `xargs`.  Rather than verifying if your `xargs` construction is safe, it's easier to avoid using it altogether (especially if you don't need it).

Try printing the 20 biggest files without `ls` and without `xargs`:

```
    find . -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -rn | head -20
```

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` takes each line of output from the previous command and basically slaps at the end of its arguments, so your find is printing something like

```
123 ./somefile.txt
```

which `xargs` turns into

```
ls -lS 123 ./somefile.txt
```

unless you actually have a file named `123` in that directory, you get your "cannot access" error:

```
marc@panic:~$ touch foo
marc@panic:~$ ls -lS file_that_does_not_exist foo
ls: cannot access file_that_does_not_exist: No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 marc marc 0 Feb  3 14:26 foo
```